# jquery Datatables sort icons put on row below the actual text?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have scoured through all my CSS files (and there are a lot of them) in addition to looking at/removing the sDom settings for my jquery Datatables plug in but for some reason, the sort icon (up and down arrows) next to my text is place below the text as if an html 
 was somehow input.

Has anybody ever had this happen before?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the table header cells with Firebug or other web dev toolkit? In most of them you can enable/disable styles one by one for the specific DOM element until you find the one that's causing it.

Comment: @fencliff - i have not, was not aware you could do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was right in front of me but apparently you have to apply the 'display' class to all table elements for the script to properly function. I had spent hours upon hours looking through CSS on this but nothing came back. I hope my time can help save somebody else a new wall.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you mean, could give me a little code snippet to fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide more description on this. I am having same issue here.

Comment: @peipst9lker @user1413 - he means to place _display_ in your _table class_ like so `<table class="display other-class"` id="dataTable">` as can be seen [here](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes#Table-classes). Everyone should be using dev tools in their browsers to test css before implementing (when possible) to avoid spending valuable time reloading pages in order to view the effects

Answer (score 5):

this is how I solved this

```
.css_right
{
    /* adding this keeps the sort icon on the same level as the label */
    float:right;
}
```

The icon already has this class, but for some reason it doesn't have the style(s) to correclty display

Answer (score 0):

I find the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) extension for Firefox to be invaluable when debugging CSS issues.

You can disable and modify the CSS styles on your page "live". Really takes the guesswork out of the style inheritance mess that can otherwise be night impossible to solve.

[image]

Image from the Firebug website at http://getfirebug.com/css.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Interestingly, the entire page malfunctions (only in Firefox). It works without any issue in IE, Chrome, and Safari. I am now more lost than I was before.

Comment: no luck. if I delete every piece of css (and i mean every) with the exception of the google cdn .css file, the issue still exists.