# How can I force the jQuery Datatables header sort icon to the far right or far left of the cell?

Tags: jquery, datatables

The Datatables sort icon, on column headers, by default appears under the column header text. I'd like to have this appear on the same line and on the far right side or far left side of the header cell.

Here's how the HTML for one of the column headers appears (in Firebug).

```
<th class="ui-state-default" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 252px;">
    <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper" style="text-align: left;">
        Account Name
        <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span>
    </div>
</th>
```

I added `display: inline-block;` to the `css-right` class on the `<span>` to force it to appear on the same line as mentioned [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/604/themeroller-sort-icons-render-on-separate-line/p1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223660/jquery-datatables-sort-icons-put-on-row-below-the-actual-text). However, I still can't find how to force the icon to appear on the far right or the far left. Adding `float:left;` or `float:right;` bumps the icon to the next line.

Any ideas?

Comment: A real sticky problem. The developer show really be informed about this. I used Datatables in number of projects an experienced the same issue. I loved development of the solution and all contribution made here. specially @user1301334 answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but here's what I see in my jQuery-UI DataTable for that symbol:

From the site's main stylesheet (not part of the jQuery UI stylesheet):

`.display thead th .DataTables_sort_wrapper span {  float: right; }`

From the jQuery UI CSS file:

```
.ui-icon { 
  display: block; 
  // ... some other stuff including overflow: hidden 
}
```

There are some other styles of course, but I think those are the ones that matter. Based on your question, I'm surprised it's not already working for you.

Comment: When I apply the styles you mentioned, both the text and the icon float right. I'd like to keep the text where it is on the left and float the icon to the right, or float the icon to the left of the text.

Comment: So hard to say. I remember I had to futz around a bit, and it's likely that we both have other styles that are different from one-another. If you have a live link, I can pook around..?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a live link because the code is hosted on an internal company site. If this question stays out there, unanswered, long enough, I may put something together on jsFiddle to play with.

Comment: Greg, after much searching through the css and messing with jsFiddle, I found that I overlooked one thing. The table I'm working with lacked the `class="display"` attribute. Because the css (`.display thead th .DataTables_sort_wrapper span`) was dependent on it, the sort icons were not rendering properly. Additionally, the css that does it is: `padding-right: 20px; position: relative;` on DataTables_sort_wrapper and: `position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50%;` on `DataTables_sort_wrapper span`. Thanks for your answer, it lead me to that conclusion.

Comment: Between jQuery UI, DataTables, and site-specific classes, it sure becomes tricky to keep track of them. :-) Glad my answer helped you find a conclusion, even if it wasn't self-contained.

Answer (score 14):

For me `table.display` did not exist, I added the following:

```
table.dataTable thead th div.DataTables_sort_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

table.dataTable thead th div.DataTables_sort_wrapper span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
    right: 0;
}
```

The above worked for me.

Comment: Matt K's answer is the same, but he did that more than a year earlier than you.

Answer (score 7):

Though Greg's answer lead me to the solution (and is the answer I accepted), for clarity, and as a help to others that might run into this issue, I'm adding my own answer.

What most affects the positioning of the sort icons is this default DataTables CSS:

```
table.display thead th div.DataTables_sort_wrapper {
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

table.display thead th div.DataTables_sort_wrapper span {
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```

If the `class="display"` attribute is not on the table, the CSS above is not applied.

Answer (score 1):

The problem being, Datatables [often] places the sort button under the text.

The OP specifically wanted the button on the right or the left of the text;
however, Steve Teale of http://britseyeview.com/ has a solution which moves the sort buttons up above the text and to the top-right of the cell.  Meaning, the sort button is always top-right, but sometimes over the text.  Basically he resets the original CSS.

> Steve writes: If I use the out-of-box background styles that implement these [sort buttons], they appear behind the column name, so instead I used:

```
.sorting_asc {
  padding-right:18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('sort_asc.png') no-repeat top right;
}

.sorting_desc {
  padding-right:18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('sort_desc.png') no-repeat top right;
}

.sorting {
  padding-right:18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('sort_both.png') no-repeat top right;
}

.sorting_asc_disabled {
  padding-right:18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('sort_asc_disabled.png') no-repeat top right;
}

.sorting_desc_disabled {
  padding-right:18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat top right;
}
```

You will need to add your path to the "background: url('/your/path/sort_both.png')".

Steve's "**Getting Started with Datatables**" is here:
http://britseyeview.com/software/dtgs/

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of Datatables(as of 31 march 15).
inside the datatables CSS change the following-

```
table.table thead .sorting,
table.table thead .sorting_asc,
table.table thead .sorting_desc,
table.table thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.table thead .sorting_desc_disabled {

    cursor: pointer;
    *cursor: hand;
    background-position: left center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

table.table thead .sorting { background: url('../img/sort_both.png') no-repeat center left; }
table.table thead .sorting_asc { background: url('../img/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center left; }
table.table thead .sorting_desc { background: url('../img/sort_desc.png') no-repeat center left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answers above, I used the following (based on the earlier insight).
The benefit for me is that no additional padding is added on the right, which is helpful for columns that do not have a sort icon. (DataTables still assigns the DataTable_sort_wrapper class).

```
table.dataTable th>div.DataTables_sort_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table.dataTable th > div.DataTables_sort_wrapper > span.DataTables_sort_icon.css_right {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
    background-position: left center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```