# Remove sorting arrows in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am using the **jQuery DataTables** plugin.

Is there a way I can get rid of the little arrows they display in the headers to indicate sorting options ? 
I would like to keep the functionality that by click on a header it sorts by this column, I just dont want to display the arrow icons as they change the layout of my column headers.

Firebug shows my headers as follows:

```
<th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 151px;" aria-label="Category: activate to sort column ascending">Category</th>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The icons is defined as `background : url(..)` on the CSS classes. Disable them by :

```css
.sorting, .sorting_asc, .sorting_desc {
    background : none;
}
```

see jsfiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/5V2Dx/** Note : This solution is for datatables 1.9.x!!

---

**Update**. When using datatables 1.10.x, the CSS for resetting the header icons is a little bit different :

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting, 
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc, 
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
    background : none;
}
```

see -> **http://jsfiddle.net/kqpv3ub9/** (updated demo is using dataTables **1.10.11**)

Comment: I need the same solution but I cannot get this option to work. I put this css script in my file but it does not remove the arrows. Any thoughts?

Comment: @LargeTuna, see update. I guess you are using datatables 1.10.x.

Comment: did work for me but this did `
    .dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*=sort]:after{
        display:none;
    }`

Comment: table.dataTable thead .sorting {
  background: none;
} worked in 2018 :

Comment: @xtlc, rubbish, the answer you suggest just disables sorting entirely, it is not an answer to the question. You could do that 7 years ago, and you can do that i 2020, **but disabling the sorting feature is not what this question is about, it is about removing the sorting arrows ...**

Comment: On re-reading the question I see that it was more related to hiding the icons and not disabling the functionality (which hides the icons, but was not what OP asked for). 
I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 54):

None of the presented solutions worked for me. But I have just found this one;

```
.dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*="sort"]:before,
.dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*="sort"]:after {
    content: "" !important;
}
```

PS.: DataTables version `"datatables": "~1.10.2"`

Comment: This is the right answer. All above is not working for me. I have DataTables 1.10.10.

Comment: +1; This is the correct answer **IF** you are using [**dataTables Bootstrap styling plugin**](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap).

Comment: had to add :before and :after

Comment: .dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*='sort']:before,
.dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*='sort']:after {
    content: '' !important;
}

Comment: Works perfect. Most other solutions detailed below didn't work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 34):

You can use the datatable properties like below, it will hide the sorting icon 
from datatable columns :

```
"targets": 'no-sort',
"bSort": false,
"order": []
```

Comment: This is the best answer as you don't need to manipulate css style.. Thanks @Edgar

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on datatable 1.10.19 and looks like the "official" way to do it. this should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Great @cetipabo:)

Comment: is there a way to override? I did this to another table and worked, but I tried in another one, but it's still there.

Comment: Will this also disable the sorting?

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran I guess yes, try it.

Comment: Great answer, solved my problem in a second :)

Answer (score 15):

(Since **DataTables 1.10**) If you don't need it, disabling ordering is one way to prevent the arrow controls from appearing. Do this on table initialization by specifying the **"ordering"** option as **false**.

**Example**:

```
$("#example").DataTable({
   "ordering": false
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78hho4gk/2/)**

**[Documentation:](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering)**

> Enable or disable ordering of columns - it is as simple as that!

**Caveat: *no sorting at all.***

Another alternative is to disable ordering across all columns. Then you can set ordering programmatically with the **control arrow(s) only displaying on sorted column(s)**:

```
var after = $('#after').DataTable({
  "order": [[1,"asc"]],                       // sorting 2nd column
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": "_all" } // Applies the option to all columns
  ]
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nobrxftw/1/)**

Comment: Adding `"orderable": false` inside the `"columnDefs": [...]` worked like a charm - this should be the accepted answer nowadays:

`"columnDefs": [ { "orderable": false, "targets": [1,2] }, ...]`

Answer (score 12):

Quick trick (this will hide a sort button, but function still works):
- Create CSS:

```css
.no-sort::after { display: none!important; }

.no-sort { pointer-events: none!important; cursor: default!important; }
```

- Then add this into a header of your table:

```html
<th class="no-sort">Heading</th>
```

Anyway here is long answer, you can use this piece of code to disable sort function of the particular column (base-idx: 0), AS WELL AS remove a sort button:

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

But this won't work perfectly if you set orderable as false in the first column. The sort function will stop but the button is still there. Because, by default, the first column was set to order ascendingly ('order': [[ 0, 'asc' ]). To disable this 'annoying' default, add one more option: "order":

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
      "columnDefs": [
        { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
      ],
      "order": [],  // not set any order rule for any column.
});
```

Comment: First solution worked for me  with this css style:
`.no-sort::before { display: none!important; }`

Answer (score 9):

For new version of DataTables:

```
<style>
     .dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*="sort"]::after{display: none}
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

The arrows have certain classes associated with them. You can use the following CSS to hide those elements.

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This all seems a bit complicated why not use the `data-sortable="false"`  attribute on the `<th>` tag and then just do a `removeAttribute("class");` in JS with a `click` trigger?

Comment: Thanks! data-sortable="false" did it for me

Comment: didn't work here.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS:

```
.DataTables_sort_icon { display:none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me

```
.dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*=sort]:after{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the latest version of datatables / CDN it is again different

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after
{
    display: none;
}
```

Hides the filters.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:before {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Works on my machine with DT 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
<display:column property="......" title="......" sortable="true"/>
```

This will make the column sortable without displaying the arrow's.

Answer (score 1):

One way I did not see on the previous answers and I believe is the best way to do it is using jQuery DataTable. This way you have more control over the events of the table and how to interact with it.

```
$('.tableclass').dataTable({
  "order":[[0,"desc"],[1,"asc"]], //Enable ordering by first column then second
  "aoColumnDefs": [
    { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ "_all" ] } //disable ordering events and takeout the icon
   ]
 });
```

Of course the CSS option still a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

For DataTables 1.10.7 a little variant for [davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407478/davidkonrad) css style:

```
table.dataTable thead th.sorting, 
table.dataTable thead th.sorting_asc, 
table.dataTable thead th.sorting_desc {
    background : none;
}
```

Include the "th" element.

Answer (score 0):

This will let you change out the default sorting icons for custom icons, which I derived from Irshad's post above and Suschil's post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591953/how-can-i-force-the-jquery-datatables-header-sort-icon-to-the-far-right-or-far-l). Had to do this due to browsers with font rendering disabled, which was out of our control.

```
.dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*="sort"]::after{display: none}

table.dataTable thead .sorting { background: url('/Content/images/sort-both.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc { background: url('/Content/images/sort-asc-list.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.tabledataTable thead .sorting_desc { background: url('/Content/images/sort-desc-list.png') no-repeat center right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this worked fine.

```
.sorting:after,
.sorting_asc:after,
.sorting_desc:after{
    content: "";
    background: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
 #sample_1>thead>tr>th.sorting, #sample_1>thead>tr>th.sorting_asc, #sample_1>thead>tr>th.sorting_desc {
        background : none;

    }
    #sample_1>thead>tr>th.sorting:after, #sample_1>thead>tr>th.sorting_asc:after, #sample_1>thead>tr>th.sorting_desc::after {
        content: none; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS classes `sorting_asc` and `sorting_desc` brings the icon.

Easiest solution to localize fix for specific table is, once table is initialized, in fnInitComplete, do the following:

`$(TABLE).find("thead th").removeClass("sorting_asc");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sample_1 thead tr th:first-child').removeClass('sorting');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below CSS. It will hide the icon only, however sorting will work.

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
  background-image: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your page

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting::after {
    opacity: 0.2;
    content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can remove the icon images as well (instead of adding new CSS), in folder:

`DataTables-1.10.16\images`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an other solution to hide the sorting icons from a column,
Apply a css class to the header let say,

```
<th class="sorting_disabled"></th>
```

and define the css class in style

```
.sorting_disabled
{
   background-image:none !important;
}
```

> This solution worked and tested for jquery datatable  version 1.10+

Comment: OR (in the same vein) change the css for th.sorting

Comment: @BenA.Hilleli I didn't understand, please come again.

Comment: Instead of adding a brand-new class (which requires more css, another item to think about), we can override the css for the existing class, i.e.  th in dataTables that is sortable will already have class "sorting", just override th.sorting { background: none; }
And if that doesn't override it (due to being less specific than other css call), add specificity: table.dataTable thead th.sorting - which saves you from using "!important" (!important is a pet peeve for modular/over-ride-able css); ......or perhaps just remove .sorting class

Answer (score 0):

The next code worked for me:

For the asc arrow, I used the next css:

```
   table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
      background-image: none;
   }
```

**To find it is easy**: Use the chrome debugger to find the column and start disabling the related styles. Then you will find the related CSS.

Use the same approach to disable the desc arrow.

Peace!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to include the "important" qualifier

```
   <style>
        table.dataTable thead .sorting, 
        table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc, 
        table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc { background : none !important};
    </style>
```

and make sure that this comes after all of the other .css files.

Answer (score 0):

Go to dataTables.boostrap.min.css or dataTables.bootstrap.css, search for `content:"↑"` and remove the arrow and that will work.